# How to insert json data into mysql table using nodejs with json data

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I shown in below code is it required to send all columns of table.

```
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(uploadPath);
        try {
            student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
           // emp = student.employee;
           gstr2recon=student.cptyRecons;
           finPeriod=student.finPeriod;
      //console.log('gstr2recon',gstr2recon);

      jsonData['finperiod']=student['finperiod'];
      jsonData['cname']=student.cptyRecons['cname'];
      jsonData['total']=student.cptyRecons['totalCnt'];
      jsonData['matched']=student.cptyRecons['matchedCnt'];
      jsonData['mismatched']=student.cptyRecons['mismatchedCnt'];
      jsonData['onhold']=student.cptyRecons['onHoldCnt'];
      jsonData['pendinginasp']=student.cptyRecons['pendingCnt'];
      jsonData['availingstn']=student.cptyRecons['avlGstnCnt'];
      jsonData['email']=student.cptyRecons['cemail'];


           var database = mysql.createConnection({
            host:'192.168.1.1',
            port:'3306',
            user:'root',
            password:'password',
            database:'ui_support'
           });
           database.connect(function(connectionError){
            if(connectionError){
              throw connectionError;
            }
            console.log('jsonData',jsonData);
            var sql = "INSERT INTO gstr2Recon(finperiod,cname,ctin,total,matched,mismatched,onhold,pendinginasp,availingstn,email) VALUES ('" + jsonData + "')";
            database.query(sql, function(queryError, queryResult){
              if(queryError){
                throw queryError;
              }
            });
          });
```

I need to insert some column data with matching json key value.

Comment: you must parse JSON and set each field individually.

Comment: If there is a complex array inside an object.Then doing this approach would be difficult.In Java we directly store objects.Do we have any such process of converting the text data to object and saving in database.

Answer (score 0):

its typo mistake

```
jsonData['finperiod']=student['finPeriod'];
```

Please you follow column name sequence and typo mistakes while assign.